# Variables and functions defined in inherited class run in base class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across weird behavior in Python 3.6.
I was able to call function and access variable defined only in child class from base class method.
I find this useful in my code but I come from C++ and this code looks very weird.
Can someone please explain this behavior?

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.var)
        self.checker()

class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var=5
        super().__init__()
    def checker(self):
        print('inside B checker')

myB = b()
```

Output:

```
5
inside B checker
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All methods in Python are looked up dynamically. You're calling a method on `self`, and `self` is a `b` instance, and `b` instances have a `checker` method, so that method gets called.

Consider this code at the module top level, or in a top-level function:

```
myB = b()
myB.checker()
```

Obviously the global module code isn't part of the `b` class definition, and yet, this is obviously legal. Why should it be any different if you put the code inside the `class a` definition, and rename `myB` to `welf`? Python doesn't care. You're just asking the value—whether you've called it `myB` or `self`—"do you have something named `checker`?", and the answer is yes, so you can call it.

And `var` is even simpler; `self.var` just adds `var` to `self.__dict__`, so it's there; the fact that it's a `b` instance isn't even relevant here (except indirectly—being a `b` instance means it had `b.__init___` called n it, and that's where `var` was created).

If you're wondering how this "asking the value", a slightly oversimplified version is:

- Every object has a `__dict__`. When you do `self.var=5`, that actually does `self.__dict__['var'] = 5`. And when you `print(self.var)`, that does `print(self.__dict__['var'])`.
- When that raises a `KeyError`, as it will for `self.checker`, Python tries `type(self).__dict__['checker']`, and, if that doesn't work, it loops over `type(self).mro()` and tries all of those dicts.
- When all of those raise a `KeyError`, as they would with `self.spam`, Python calls `self.__getattr__('spam')`.
- If even that fails, you get an `AttributeError`.

---

Notice that if you try to construct an `a` instance, this will fail with an `AttributeError`. That's because now `self` is an `a`, not a `b`. It doesn't have a `checker` method, and it hasn't gone through the `__init__` code that adds a `var` attribute.

---

The reason you can't do this in C++ is that C++ methods are looked up statically. It's not a matter of what type the value is at runtime, but what type the variable is at compile time. If the statically looked-up method says it's virtual, then the compiler inserts some dynamic-lookup code, but otherwise, it doesn't.<sup>1</sup>

One way it's often explained is that in Python (and other languages with SmallTalk semantics, like ObjC and Ruby), all methods are automatically virtual. But that's a bit misleading, because in C++, even with virtual methods, the method name and signature still has to be findable on the base class; in Python (and SmallTalk, etc.), that isn't necessary.

If you're thinking this must be horribly slow, that Python must have to do something like search some stack of namespaces for the method by name every time you call a method—well, it does that, but it's not as slow as you've expect. For one thing, a namespace is a dict, so it's a constant-time search. And the strings are interned and have their hash values cached. And the interpreter can even cache the lookup results if it wants to. The result *is* still slower than dereferencing a pointer through a vtable, but not by a huge margin (and besides, there are plenty of *other* things in Python that can be 20x slower than C++, like `for` loops; you don't use pure Python when you need every detail to work as fast as possible).

---

<sub>1. C++ also has another problem: even if you defined a `var` attribute and a `checker` virtual method in `a`, you don't get to choose the order the initializers get called; the compiler automatically calls `a`'s constructor first, then `b`'s. In Python, it calls `b.__init__`, and you choose when you want to call `super().__init__()`, whether it's at the start of the method, at the end, in the middle, or even never.</sub>

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot for clarifying this important topic

Answer (score 0):

First you are creating an instance of `class b` which will call the constructor of class b `__init__`.

Inside the constructor your are setting the attribute `self.var` as 5.Later `super().__init__()` will call the constructor of the parent class A.

Inside the constructor of `class A` both `self.var` is printed and `self.checker()` is called.

Note that when calling the `super().__init__()` will place the child class instance `self` as the first argument by default.